# Update Asset Indexes gives "getFileList() is not implemented"

Tags: assets

Thank you in advance for any tips on this.

Barely-related-background: I made a mistake on my development machine. In gparted, I chose "ignore" instead of "cancel". This is called 'choosing poorly'. Anyway, I now have freshly reinstalled my OS, apache, php, etc.

Now, as the title says, when I click "Update Asset Indexes" it gives a popup saying `getFileList() is not implemented`

Any suggestions what I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception in thrown in the class `craft\volumes\MissingVolume` that states one of your Volumes has an invalid class

```php
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getFileList(string $directory, bool $recursive): array
{
    throw new NotSupportedException('getFileList() is not implemented.');
}
```

Maybe you uninstalled a plugin that adds a certain Volume class like S3 or something?

Comment: Thank you, Robin. If I disable all plugins, the problem persists. 
The only installed plugins, by the way, are Redactor, Wordsmith, Environment Label, Element Index Defaults, and my own calendar plugin. Could it be something other than a plugin?

Comment: Disabling a plugin causes the issue... You should check all volumes and ther classes/types. You can also go into your DB and check if there is anything besides a local volume

Comment: OK, yes, you nailed it. In Craft2 we had used S3 as a volume for a while, but then stopped using it but left it there, but Craft3 requires (and offers) a plugin for S3, and I didn't have the plugin.  So for this case, I just deleted the unneeded S3 volume and all fixed.